# How to seal old subfloor with coper sulphate preservative?

Tags: flooring, subfloor

I purchased an old home a month ago. Slept there 3 different occasions for one night at a time and every time I felt unwell for days.
Last time after removing the carpet I noticed copper green residue on the old subfloor. It looked like old green mold also. I decided to wash the subfloor with bleach water and castor soap. Next morning again I woke with bluish shadow under my eye and red eyelids to my eyebrow. My eye, mouth felt very dry that still lasting after 4 days. After researching how to seal subfloor, I realized that the chemical might be responsible for feeling ill is the copper sulphate used to preserve/protect the subfloor from mould.
I can’t afford to replace the subfloor but would like to seal it with something not toxic then seal with air tight sheet under the new vinyl floor that will go on top of the old subfloor. Is there any sealer that can completely cover copper sulphate and does not react and make it worse.  I am thinking lime wash mixed with linseed oil. The lime wash will cover the wood surface, and the oil will prevent copper sulphate from becoming airborne.

Comment: Lime is a base, while copper sulphate is acidic. If you're already sensitive to the relatively undisturbed copper sulphate then the potential for fumes created by mixing those two is unlikely to do you any favors. I'd suggest you consider a solution closer to the 21st century instead, like a low-VOC water-based sealer or even a decent paint primer.

Answer (score 1):

**Woah!**  You must identify the problem before throwing solutions at it.  Just two possibilities are biological such as fungus and environmental such as fumes from a (past or present) furnace.  Many possibilities.  For example it might have been used to store some 'safe' chemical but dampness produced nasty gasses.

I've never heard of Copper Sulphate being used in building so I would suspect your house has a bit of a chequered past *to put it mildly*.

Practical steps:

1. Visit as little as possible for your own safety.  Absolutely minimum.  Don't let any children or contractors onto the site until you've found the cause.
2. Ask neighbours for local history.
3. Start with your local environmental health department and ask them what you should do *to discover the cause*.

There's no escaping that you have some bad news.  Amateur attempts could make things a lot worse.  You also have a legal liability for anybody who enters the premises.  In case you need to sue the seller you must start documenting everything in excruciating detail.

Comment: From a DIY/Home-Improvement perspective, this is really not an answer to the question.

Comment: I agree with you, @brhans, but we have had people use answers to point out legitimate concerns that weren't directly in scope of the original question and were too big for a comment. This seems like it could be one of those cases.